# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in MYSQL works in first table not second

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach

I keep getting this Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in when i launch the PHP. I'm mainly posting here because the foreach works like charm for the first table (as shown in the URL at the bottom)

```
<?php
//connect to MySQL
include("inc_connect_database.php");

//selet database
mysql_select_db("fo8(ell");

$query = "SELECT * FROM graphicscard " ;

$results = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

// DISPLAY RECORDS FROM THE graphicscard table
echo "<table border=\"1\">\n";
echo "graphicscard table" . "<BR/>";
echo "id | name | nvidia | AMD";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
  echo "<tr>\n";
  foreach($row as $value) {
    echo "<td>\n";
    echo $value;
    echo "</td>\n";
  }
  echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

// DISPLAY RECORDS FROM THE computertype table

$query = "SELECT * FROM computertype " ;

$results = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

// DISPLAY RECORDS FROM THE graphicscard table
echo "<table border=\"1\">\n";
echo "computertype table" . "<BR/>";
echo "id | label";

echo "<tr>\n";
foreach($row as $value) {
  echo "<td>\n";
  echo $value;
  echo "</td>\n";
}
echo "</tr>\n";

echo "</table>\n"
?>
```

Weird thing it... the exact foreach works fine in the first table creation.. but not the second. Thats why im coming here. Link below displays how the first foreach works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for the second query because you don't have this block outside of foreach:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
//blah-blah
}
```

call `mysql_fetch_assoc`, and it will work.